# Execute a Snakemake workflow via Tibanna on AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, snakemake

I am trying to execute the workflow of the Snakemake's official tutorial via Tibanna on AWS.

As instructed [here](https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/executing/cloud.html#executing-a-snakemake-workflow-via-tibanna-on-amazon-web-services),

1. I have installed Tibanna and set up environment variables.
2. Then I deployed Tibanna Unicorn to a folder *snakemake-tutorial* in a specific S3 bucket *specific-bucket*.
3. I set up the default unicorn.
4. As a last step, I run the following command:

```
$ snakemake --tibanna --default-remote-prefix=specific-bucket/snakemake-tutorial
```

However, I get an error at bwa_map rule. And the log says that:

```
/bin/bash: bwa: command not found
/bin/bash: samtools: command not found
```

For some reason, I am not able to use conda and/or packages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this problem with the `--precommand` flag.

```
snakemake --tibanna --default-remote-prefix=sm-tut-test/sm --precommand="conda install -c bioconda bwa"
```

I am still investigating for an elegant solution though.

---

**Added later:**
I found a better solution using [*Integrated package management* feature](https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/latest/snakefiles/deployment.html?highlight=cookiecutter#integrated-package-management).